# Can Packer build an AMI locally (that is, without connecting to AWS)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, provisioning, amazon-ami, packer

Assume I have some special use-case. Please no answers like "why do you want to do this?" Simply put, is this supported behavior, and if so, could you point me to the relevant documentation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can import into AWS for the following [image formats](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmimport-image-import.html):

- Open Virtualization Archive (OVA)
- Virtual Machine Disk (VMDK)
- Virtual Hard Disk (VHD/VHDX)
- Raw

Packer supports:

- [vmware](https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/vmware/) which can be [exported as an OVF template](https://docs.vmware.com/).
- [hyper-v](https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/hyperv/) which can be [exported as virtual machine or virtual hard disks](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831535.aspx).

AWS provides further instructions on how to import your VM as image [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmimport-image-import.html#import-vm-image).